# Validating schema of my XSD wth GML with GeoTools

Tags: java, geotools, gml, validation, xsd

I would like to control if my GML file is valid with my actual XSD using GeoTools.

I found something here: [GML2 Parsing TestSchema Example](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/xml/geometry.html#gml2-parsing-testschema-example). But I don't know if it's a good way to do what I want.

```
Configuration configuration = new org.geotools.gml3.GMLConfiguration();
Parser parser = new org.geotools.xsd.Parser(configuration);

//the xml instance document above
ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream xsd = classloader.getResourceAsStream("gml/config.xsd");

int i =0;
//parse
SimpleFeatureCollection fc = (SimpleFeatureCollection) parser.parse(xsd);
fc.accepts( new AbstractFeatureVisitor(){
    public void visit( Feature feature ) {
        SimpleFeature f = (Feature) i.next();

        Point point = (Point) f.getDefaultGeometry();
        String name = (String) f.getAttribute( "name" );
    }
}, new NullProgressListener() );
```

In my code I don't know where I can specify my GML file for validation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a GML aware parser to check for validity a normal Java XML `Validator` will do. So something like:

```
  public boolean validate(File gml, URL schemaURL) {
    Source xmlFile = new StreamSource(gml);
    SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    try {
      Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaURL);
      Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
      validator.validate(xmlFile);
      System.out.println(xmlFile.getSystemId() + " is valid");
      return true;
    } catch (SAXException e) {
      System.out.println(xmlFile.getSystemId() + " is NOT valid reason:" + e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: Yes but actually I have proxy and when I use this method I have the same error.

Comment: You can configure a proxy with the VM arguments -Dhttp.proxyHost=<proxy.host.com> -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080